# How to list my app on the back of Passbook card?

Tags: ios, passbook

The new SPG Passbook card lists their iOS app on the back of the card in much the same way that Mobile Safari can now show a banner for sites who have an app. Example screenshot:

[image]

I wasn't able to find anything in Apple's (sparse) documentation about how you would connect them. Their Passbook card is oddly not even installed through their app, which can only show an image of your SPG card on screen. You need to go to http://spg.com/passbook on iOS to install it, which suggests it isn't the OS figuring out the connection.

Any ideas?

Comment: Oooh, is that your real SPG number?  Do you have enough points for me to get some free overwater bungalows at the Le Méridien in Bora Bora?

Comment: Sadly, no :) I would if I could though.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out! I managed to download the SPG .pkpass file and take a peek in the pass.json. They use:

"associatedStoreIdentifiers":[XXXXXXXXX]

where XXXXXXXXX is the Apple ID of your app. Tried it out and it works perfectly. It should be outside of your lower-level dictionary terms alongside your passTypeIdentifier, etc.

Comment: By lower level, do you mean its at the same level in the dictionary as `backgroundColor` and `foregroundColor` elements? Can you provide an example of the JSON file?

Comment: It should be at the same level as your `organizationName`, being the top level of the file. One important note: the app will only show up on the back of the card if it's available for the device that the card is on. If you have, for example, an iPad only app, you will only see an error message when the card is viewed on an iPhone or iPod touch.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set it up in your Apple Dev Center.
The place is the same as where you enable the In-App Purchasing, Push Notification, etc.